# Applying casts to the results of integer and floating point division: what's going on here?

Tags: java, floating-point

I'm a beginner and there's something that's not making much sense to me. Please could be so kind as to explain where I'm going wrong. I'm sorry if this has been asked before.

Here the presence of the decimal point mean these get evaluated using floating point division.

```
System.out.println(1/3.0); // this prints: 0.3333333333333333
System.out.println(1.0/3); // this prints: 0.3333333333333333
System.out.println(1.0/3.0); // this prints: 0.3333333333333333
```

Apparently, this below is an example of "truncating-integer division." It seems a bit weird to me but ok.

```
System.out.println(1/3); // this prints: 0
```

Is it ok to say: "in the line below, the (double) cast is evaluated 1st. It effectively says: "treat 1/3 as a double - don't use truncating integer division. instead use floating point division.""

```
System.out.println((double)1/3); // this prints: 0.3333333333333333
```

Below, however we get 0.0 - how did that happen?

```
System.out.println((double)(1/3)); // this prints: 0.0
```

ok so maybe the extra parentheses mean the (1/3) gets evaluated 1st. It is evaluated using truncating integer division yielding 0. And *then* the double is applied giving us 0.0 Ok that makes sense

Ok so we maybe can propose a couple of general rules here:

Rule 1: (double) expression means apply the (double) cast first then evaluate the expression.

Rule 2: (double) (expression) means evaluate the expression *then* apply the cast. 
Great!

So in the next line below we have: (int) expression, so I guess we can apply rule 1). The (int) cast is evaluated 1st. It effectively says: "treat 1.0/3 as a int - don't use as much memory as you would with a double. Don't use floating point division, instead apply truncating integer division."" So we have 0 right? No.

```
System.out.println((int)1/3.0); // this prints: 0.3333333333333333
```

Ok so we have 0.33333 so the (int) cast is not evaluated 1st. It is as if it wasn't there. Let's propose a 3rd rule:

Rule 3: (int) expression means ignore the (int) cast altogether just evaluate the expression like the (int) isn't even there.

Ok applying rule 3 to the line below, we have (int) but we are just going to ignore it.  1.0/3.0 is evaluated with floating point division and we get 0.3333333. Success!

```
System.out.println((int)1.0/3.0); // this prints: 0.3333333333333333
```

And in the last line below, again we have (int) but we are just going to ignore it. (1.0/3) is evaluated using floating point division yielding 0.3333333333 right? No.

```
System.out.println((int)(1.0/3)); // this prints: 0
```

Ok now I'm confused. Please could you help me get my head round this?

Comment: Do not formulate your own rules like that. You will confuse yourself after a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java's language parsing rules are basically implying a lot of parentheses everywhere in your code based on its rules of *order of operations*. Understanding where Java thinks the parentheses are will help you understand this behavior. When you say:

```
(double) 1 / 3.0
```

... this is equivalent to saying:

```
((double) 1) / 3.0
```

This means that 1 gets converted to a double, and 3.0 is automatically a double, so you'll end up doing a floating point division rather than integer division. The same thing would happen with `(double) 1 / 3`, because the divisor is a `double`, so even though the dividend is an `int`, the system realizes that you want to do floating-point division. The compiler doesn't want you to lose precision unless you specifically ask to, so *any time either the dividend or the divisor is a `double`, it will do `double` division*.

On the other hand:

```
(int) 1 / 3.0
```

... is the same as saying:

```
((int) 1) / 3.0
```

In this case, you're telling the compiler what it already knew: that the divisor (1) is an `int`. Then you're asking it to divide by a `double` value (3.0). Since the dividend is a `double`, it will perform `double` division.

As you noted, `1/3` will produce zero, because that's how integer division works and both numbers are integers. The same will happen with `1/(int)3.0` because you're telling the compiler to make the `3.0` into an `int` before the division will occur (as in `1/((int)3.0)`).

The final point to keep in mind is that `(int) 0.33` will also get converted to `0`, because an integer can't hold decimal values in it. So when you say `(int)(1.0/3)`, you're doing `double` division, but then you're converting the double into an `int` afterwards, producing `0`.

Comment: Ahhh ok so that makes sense now! I think maybe the rules 1 and 2 in my question are right! But I was misunderstanding how to apply the cast - what it meant. Thank you very much everyone for taking the time to help me. Stack overflow rules.

Answer (score 3):

This is specified in the [Java Language Specification - Numeric Promotions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html)

> If any of the operands is of a reference type, unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) is performed.
>
> Then:
>
> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

The concept is called widening conversion:

> 5.1.2 Widening Primitive Conversion
>
> The following 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - byte to short, int, long, float, or double
> - short to int, long, float, or double
> - char to int, long, float, or double
> - int to long, float, or double
> - long to float or double
>   float to double

The reason why

```
(int) (1.0/3) == 0
```

is because you cast the result of 1.0/3 (0.33333... by the above rules) explicitly to an integer, which is equivalent to "floor(result)" (rounding down), so the result is 0.

Cast has a higher precedence than /, that's why the other operations were misleading to your understanding:

```
(double) 1 / 3
```

will explicitly cast 1 to a double value 1.0 first, so again the result by the above rules is equal to 0.3333....

Answer (score 2):

There are two factors in all those cases:

1. [Operator precedence](http://www.uni-bonn.de/~manfear/javaoperators.php)
2. When one of the arguments of the division is a floating point number, the result is a floating point number.

I'll give three examples from your question:

1. `(double) (1/3)` - first evaluate the expression in parenthesis - (1/3) is an integer division so the result is `0`, then cast it to double, you get `0.0`
2. `(int) (1.0/3)` - first evaluate the expression in parenthesis - (1.0/3) is a floating point division, so the result is `0.3333`, then cast it to int, and you get `0`
3. (double) 1/3 - first perform casting so `(double)1` becomes 1.0, then evaluate the division `1.0/3` - this is a floating point division, so the result is `0.3333`

Answer (score 2):

The cast is only applied to the expression immediately after it.
Examples:

```
(int)1/3  
applies the cast to the 1. equivalent to ((int)1)/3

(int)(1/3)
the cast is applied to the result of the expression.

(int)((double)1.333*(float)3.167)
getting a little more complicated. 1.333 casted to double, 
multiplied by 3.167 casted to a float, with the result casted to an int
```

Hope that helps!